# POP3 username including special characters

Tags: exchange, pop3, encoding

I need to access an Mailbox in Exchange Server 2016 via POP3. Unfortunately the username contains German special characters like 'ä' or 'ß'. POP3 service just gives an `-ERR Protocol error. 17`.

Is there a possibility to access the mailbox via POP3 without changing the users name?

Answer (score 0):

Does it work on other account? Run "**Get-Mailbox | FL *Name***" to list this effected mailbox.
I experience a issue on my lab now, I will do Telnet test after I fix it.

Comment: It works on every account that does not contain special characters. The problem seems to be POP3 not beeing able to deal wirh these characters. So I hoped to find a way to work around this using Exchange Servers possibilities.